# Search Function with Multiple Conditions in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I tried to make a search function based on 4 requests; `categories`, `location`, `keyword`, and `sorting`. The search function with 3 requests (`location`, `categories`, and `sorting`) works well and has correct output.

But the problem is, when my website sent request with `keywords` data, the output results are only the result from `keywords` request only, when I try to sent a `location` / `categories` requests, the output does not change (only the output of the keyword request only)

[image: JSON Response]

Here is the code I write:

```php
    public function getBy(Request $request) {
        $categories = $request->all()['categories'];
        $location   = $request->all()['location'];
        $sorting    = $request->all()['sorting'];
        $keyword    = $request->all()['keyword'];

        //--- sorting code ---

        //keyword request
        if ($keyword === null) {
          $jobs = Job::query();
        } else {
          $jobs = Job::query()->where('job_title', 'LIKE', "%{$keyword}%")
            ->orWhere('title', 'LIKE', "%{$keyword}%")
            ->orWhere('description', 'LIKE', "%{$keyword}%")
            ->orWhereHas('users', function ($q) use ($keyword) {
              $q->where('company_name', 'LIKE', "%{$keyword}%");
            })->orWhereHas('categories', function ($q) use ($keyword) {
              $q->where('category', 'LIKE', "%{$keyword}%");
            })->orWhereJsonContains('tags', $keyword);
        }

        //location and categories request
        if ($location === [] && $categories === []) {
          $jobs;
        } elseif ($location === []) {
          $jobs->whereHas('categories', function ($q) use ($categories) {
            $q->whereIn('slugs', $categories);
          });
        } elseif ($categories === []) {
          $jobs->whereHas('location', function ($q) use ($location) {
            $q->whereIn('city_name', $location);
          });
        } else {
          $jobs->whereHas('categories', function ($q) use ($categories) {
            $q->whereIn('slugs', $categories);
          })->whereHas('location', function ($q) use ($location) {
            $q->whereIn('city_name', $location);
          });
        }

        //return as JSON
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

The main issue with your code is your `locations` and `categories` search query were not setting `$jobs` again. It should look like this:

```
 $jobs = $jobs->whereHas('categories', function ($q) use ($categories) {
     $q->whereIn('slugs', $categories);
 });
```

This will set the `$jobs` variable to include the new conditions of the query.

I would also suggest not checking if `$locations` or `$categories` are empty, as they if statements for each are dealing with the condition already. Here is some refactored code:

```
public function getBy(Request $request) {
    $sorting    = $request->all()['sorting'];

    //--- sorting code ---

    //keyword request
    if (! $keywords = request('keywords')) {
        $jobs = Job::query();
    } else {
        $jobs = Job::query()->where('job_title', 'LIKE', "%{$keyword}%")
            ->orWhere('title', 'LIKE', "%{$keyword}%")
            ->orWhere('description', 'LIKE', "%{$keyword}%")
            ->orWhereHas('users', function ($q) use ($keyword) {
                $q->where('company_name', 'LIKE', "%{$keyword}%");
            })->orWhereHas('categories', function ($q) use ($keyword) {
                $q->where('category', 'LIKE', "%{$keyword}%");
            })->orWhereJsonContains('tags', $keyword);
    }

    foreach (['categories', 'locations'] as $field) {
        if ($request->filled($field)) {
            $jobs = $jobs->whereHas($field, function ($q) use ($field) {
                $q->whereIn('slugs', request($field));
            });
        }
    }

    return $jobs->get()->toArray();
}
```

Here we loop through the `categories` and `locations` request data and see if the data is `->filled()` (is defined and not empty). If so, we run the query.

Comment: my API recieve `categories` and `locations` as an empty array `[]` if we didn't input those conditions. Also, if all of my request input is empty, it should show all the query.

Comment: `->filled()` will deal with this, as it will not process if defined and if is empty. Also, if `keywords` not passed through, it would still return all results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 public function getBy(Request $request) {
    $categories = $request->categories;
    $location   = $request->location;
    $sorting    = $request->sorting;
    $keyword    = $request->keyword;

    //--- sorting code ---


    $jobs = Job::query();

    //keyword request
    if ($keyword !== null) {
      $jobs = $jobs->where('job_title', 'LIKE', "%{$keyword}%")
        ->orWhere('title', 'LIKE', "%{$keyword}%")
        ->orWhere('description', 'LIKE', "%{$keyword}%")
        ->orWhereHas('users', function ($q) use ($keyword) {
          $q->where('company_name', 'LIKE', "%{$keyword}%");
        })->orWhereHas('categories', function ($q) use ($keyword) {
          $q->where('category', 'LIKE', "%{$keyword}%");
        })->orWhereJsonContains('tags', $keyword);
    }

    //location and categories request
    if ($location === []) {
      $jobs = $jobs->whereHas('categories', function ($q) use ($categories) {
        $q->whereIn('slugs', $categories);
      });
    } elseif ($categories === []) {
      $jobs = $jobs->whereHas('location', function ($q) use ($location) {
        $q->whereIn('city_name', $location);
      });
    } else {
      $jobs = $jobs->whereHas('categories', function ($q) use ($categories) {
        $q->whereIn('slugs', $categories);
      })->whereHas('location', function ($q) use ($location) {
        $q->whereIn('city_name', $location);
      });
    }

    return $jobs->get();
  }
```

Comment: the output given is only an empty array if there is no input request. 
If no input request is received, all data should be displayed